# Hudson Too Many E-Mails

Tags: email, maven-2, continuous-integration, hudson

When I build my maven project in Hudson, Hudson sends out two e-mails for each failure - one for the project failure, and one for the module that broke.

Is there any way to stop this, so I only get one e-mail per build failure?

Comment: Maybe you could give your extra emails to the OP on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340333/hudson-wont-send-mail  :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this is a hudson bug

http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5695